# HDMI don't works @ 60hz nor have HDR, when through DVI to HDMI adapter works @ 60hz, still no HDR

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv

I brought a new TV, TCL model P65US. My pc have a Gigabyte GTX 1060.

When i connect the PC to TV through HDMI cable (2.0), it doesn't show any image (the screen gets black), unless i make an option the TV have that says "HDMI 2.0" and set it to Disabled, and then it shows just 30hz at 4k, and don't even show the option in Win10 to enable HDR (settings -> Display) .

If a connect the PC, using very same cable, through DVI (with adapter connected to video card) to HDMI, it shows 60 hz at 4k, and it shows the option to enable HDR in Win10, but when I do this, the screen flicks and it automatically unset the option.

Why this happens? Is there a way to enable HDR with this setup?

Comment: Please, someone! Help me!!!!!

Comment: Someone help me!! Please!!!!